# Catch "Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: MySQL server has gone away" to write error nicely

Tags: php, mysqli

Where and how to write a code that will check if error showing "MySQL server has gone away" appears and print some error diferently and more nicely.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689649/solving-mysql-server-has-gone-away-errors/8689738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another post that answers this ([Solving "MySQL server has gone away" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689649/solving-mysql-server-has-gone-away-errors/8689738#8689738)) with the following code snippet:

```
try {
  $conn = getDbConn();
  saveData($conn, $val);
} catch (DbException $e) {
  if (strstr($e->getMessage(), 'MySQL server has gone away') {
    // WRITE OUT NICE LOG HERE AND RETRY IF WANTED
    ....
    // RETRY
    $conn = getDbConn();
    saveData($conn, $val);
  } else {
    // we have a problem connecting or something, pass the exception along
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should link directly to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8689738/499214) instead of the question

Comment: or better yet link the question as a duplicate through a question comment.

Comment: WHat is proper way to link dupes?

Comment: "Possible duplicate of [link]" or anything similar

Comment: Thx Jan for the helpful netiquette advice.